# POSIX sigevent not compiling with c11

Tags: c, gcc, posix, c11

I have simple app in C that is using POSIX struct sigevent.

```
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigevent sig_event;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it like this:

```
gcc test.c
```

it is fine. When I force C11 mode, it fails:

```
gcc test.c --std=c11

test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:5:21: error: storage size of ‘sig_event’ isn’t known
    struct sigevent sig_event;
```

I'm using gcc 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10. Any ideas what is causing those errors? This problem first occured when I tried to compile example from manual for timer_create() function. Situation was the same, except for much more errors.

Comment: It all boils down to that the compiler is not allowed to dump non-standard identifiers inside standard headers. When compiling for strict standard C, be it either C11 or earlier standards, gcc will stop dumping various junk in standard headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The header `<signal.h>` is part of standard C. But POSIX adds more to it. Since `struct sigevent` is not C but in POSIX `-std=c11` disables (probably an `ifdef` somewhere) it.

```
gcc test.c
```

works because gcc by default enables certain level of POSIX functions and a lot GNU extensions.

Compile it with:

```
gcc -std=c11 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809 file.c
```

Comment: I was about to add, that adding -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199309 clears the erros and I don't know why. Your answer explaint id. Thanks.

Comment: Using `-std=gnu11` instead of `-std=c11` should also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is because posix symbol is not part of C standard. This can be solved in various ways,

- `gcc -std=c11 -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 file.c`
- `gcc -std=c11 -D_GNU_SOURCE file.c`
- `gcc -std=gnu11 file.c`

Here `700` means X Open7 Posix 2008.